# Add a value to an existing key in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a structure like:

```
server1: {
  OS: Win_2016,
  Role: CT
},
server2: {
  OS: RHEL7,
  Role: POM
}
```

I want to merge it with:

```
server1: {
  MAC: 00:01:02:03:04:05
},
server2: {
  MAC: 00:01:02:03:04:06
}
```

All my attempts have ended up with one overwriting the other.

BTW: at this point the servers have been created in oVirt and Foreman but never run so I can't use the normal fact gathering.  And I need to know the MAC so I can pass it to WDS to start the VM for the first time.

How do I actually merge them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your example data structure was neither valid as json nor yaml.

Meanwhile it was sufficiently explicit so I corrected it as pure yaml in my below example. Fix this accordingly depending on your exact data source.

In ansible, you can merge dictionnaries with the [`combine` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries). Since you have nested elements, you will have to use the `recursive=true` option.

The following playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: combine dict demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    dict1:
      server1:
        OS: Win_2016
        Role: CT
      server2:
        OS: RHEL7
        Role: POM

    dict2:
      server1:
        MAC: "00:01:02:03:04:05"
      server2:
        MAC: "00:01:02:03:04:06"

  tasks:
    - name: combine the dicts
      debug:
        msg: "{{ dict1 | combine(dict2, recursive=true) }}"
```

Gives the following result:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [combine dict demo] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [combine the dicts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "server1": {
            "MAC": "00:01:02:03:04:05",
            "OS": "Win_2016",
            "Role": "CT"
        },
        "server2": {
            "MAC": "00:01:02:03:04:06",
            "OS": "RHEL7",
            "Role": "POM"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you, that works.  I was sure I'd tried this but obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

I think is quite simple, I think you just need to add a new dictionarie to your dictionaries,

take a look to this and let me now if your problem has been solved.

```
server1 = {"OS": "Win_2016", "Role": "CT"}
server2 = {"OS": "RHEL7", "Role": "POM"}

print(server1)
print(server2)

server1["MAC"] = "00:01:02:03:04:05" # Here I´m just adding the new key "MAC" 
server2["MAC"] = "00:01:02:03:04:06" # Here is happening the same, with its respective value

print(server1)
print(server2)
```

Comment: I wasn't specific enough.  I'm looking for an ansible solution.